# Как сделать сортировку по первой букве в DBGrid

Tags: c++, база-данных, c++builder, dbgrid

Есть таблица в базе данных, в которой имеется Фамилия Имя и Отчество человека, она подключена к проекту C++ Builder, как сделать сортировку по первой букве Фамилии в этом самом проекте?

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Sername

Comment: В AdoQuery, когда прописываешь SQL код пишешь Order By (поле фамилии)